# How do I use numeric functions to correct date typos?

Tags: sas

I know it's easy enough to do manual corrections on date typos, but I want to automate such corrections using one or more SAS functions, given that my dataset is large and typos are frequent.

For instance, it seems that whomever created the dataset I am cleaning often transposed digits in the year of someone's birthdate (e.g., '2102' rather than '2012', '2110' instead of '2010', etc). I'm aware of string functions such as INDEX() that find certain character values or strings and then allow for the replacement of said characters in the same position (i.e., replace "ABCD" with "ABBB", regardless of the string's location in a value). Can the same process be replicated with numeric (and specifically date) values?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example of the SAS data you are working on and the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think SAS has any functions that would check numeric values for digit patterns. I often do data cleaning and address this issue by making a character variable out of the numeric date variable, then using character functions and Perl regex to clean the character values, and then storing the cleaned values as numeric date.

For specifically date values, you could try using SAS date functions (e.g. DAY(), MONTH(), YEAR(), MDY(), etc.) to extract parts of the date value, error-check them, and put them all back together into a date value. This could be a good quick solution if you expect a limited set of typos and you roughly know what they are. For a more thorough error check, converting the numeric values to character and using char or regex functions would give you more options.

Answer (score 0):

The only really concise suggestion I can imagine is using `mdy` (Assuming this is date, not datetime variables).

For example:

```
data want;
 set have;
 if year(datevar) > 2100 then
   datevar = mdy(month(datevar),day(datevar),year(datevar)-90);
run;
```

would correct any '2104' to '2014'.  That's a very simple correction (and may well do as much harm as good, since '2114' is also a possible typo), but things along those lines - break the date up into its pieces, verify the pieces, reconstruct using `mdy`.